# linq select items from child collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Below are my classes. I have a product that contains list of days. Each day has a city property.

I need to create a linq query that will give me the distinct cities that are used on all my products in the system.

I tried something like this but it does not work:

```
var cities = from product in NHibernateSession.Linq<Product>() select new { city = product.Days.Where(d => d.City != null).Distinct() }; //This returns the day items but i need distinct cities

   public class Product : EntityBase
   {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<ProductDayDefinition> Days { get; set; }
   }

   public class ProductDayDefinition : EntityBase
   {
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to call the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534336.aspx) function, which takes a single item and lets you get multiple items from it.

For example:

```
var cities = NHibernateSession.Linq<Product>()
                .SelectMany(p => p.Days)
                .Select(p => p.City)
                .Where(c => c != null)
                .Distinct();
```

Note that if the `City` class doesn't implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` correctly, this will return duplicates.

You can do this using query comprehension syntax like this:  (Untested)

```
var cities = (from product in NHibernateSession.Linq<Product>() 
              from day in product.Days
              where day.City != null
              select day).Distinct();
```

Comment: When my Property equivalent to Days is null in all my equivalent Product Class Objects, I get a 'System.NullReferenceException'.  How do I avoid that Exception (i.e. without first explicitly (i.e. via a separate Statement) scanning Product Class Objects first to ensure at least one has a non-null Days Property)?  Hoping for something like a Null Conditional Operator.

Comment: @Tom: Either add `where product.Days != null` first or add `?? Enumerable.Empty<T>()`.  I don't know how that would work with a query provider, though.